# SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter animations

Tags: android, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I have been using SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter from https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter. It is working great. I would like to start adding some animations. I downloaded and installed the test/example app, and inspected the code for the animation example. I cannot understand what part of the code for the example makes the animations work as they do.
Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations are triggered when any of the [notify](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object)) methods of the `RecyclerView.Adapter` are called. In the example below the RecyclerView will animate the insertion of an item in a specific position:

```java
adapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
```

The library provide extra [notify methods](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter/blob/544f1896ceee04960127e5b693e288716e24f3a8/library/src/main/java/io/github/luizgrp/sectionedrecyclerviewadapter/SectionNotifier.java)  to help trigger the animation for specific items of the sections, like [this one](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/luizgrp/sectionedrecyclerviewadapter/demo/example8/Example8Fragment.java#L166).

Comment: Thanks Gustavo, I couldn't figure out why it was not working in my code. Your explanation helped a lot.